# Eclipse errors won't appear or disappear unless project is saved

Tags: java, eclipse

Errors in my code won't appear until I save the project.
Not even warnings are popping up until I save.
All that it says whenever I type something in is "1 changed line"

Comment: Do you have "Project > Build Automatically" checked?

Comment: I do have "Project > Build Automatically" on but I still have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the fix was to disable Annotation Processing:

1. Open project properties
2. Java Compiler -> Annotation Processing
3. Disable "Enable annotation processing"

[image: Project properties screenshot]

After disabling, warnings and errors are displayed immediatly (if "Build automatically" is checked, as mentioned by @greg-449). Also code completion, refactorings and quick fix etc. are much faster and smoother.

This also removes the .apt_generated folder in the project structure.

I didn't face any problems after disabling it. If you face problems, like Annotations not beeing checked during compilation, you may have to enable annotation processing but specifing the options and provide the source containing the annotation in the "Factory Path" sub-option (Java Compiler > Annotation Processing > Factory Path).